# paho loop issue in python on raspbian

Tags: python, mqtt, raspbian, paho

I am attempting to write a python script (for Raspbian) that sends mqtt message on button pushes, and changes LED's on/off when mqtt messages are received.

I can send no worries, and my script structure on 4 RPi's is the same;

```
import
set variables
while true:
   do stuff endlessly
```

I however can not get a basic script running for paho to receive in this structure.

I tried to follow the paho guide but can not adapt it to an endless while loop application.

Why can't I receive mqtt messages?  I cross check with 2 terminals; mosquito sub & pub, they are definitely been sent/received elsewhere on network.

Edit;
New on_connect callback displays "Connected" every 2 seconds, but the script still doesn't receive/print mqtt messages.  It still does send them when I push the button.

Attempted to fire up a different MQTT broker in Docker, made no difference.

Edit3; WORKS!  :D  Last I test I must not have been awake and had the subscribe line commented out in the on_connect callback.
I also removed the "P1" from the mqtt.Client thing which I copied from a tutorial.

Can happierly confirm, it sends and receives mqtt messages.  Now I can integrate into my larger script.  Thanks hardlib

New code is this;

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt') 
import os
import time
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from gpiozero import Button
from time import sleep

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    print("message received " ,str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")))
    print("message topic=",message.topic)
    print("message qos=",message.qos)
    print("message retain flag=",message.retain)

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    client.subscribe("button")

button = Button(25)
broker_address="192.168.1.10"
client = mqtt.Client()

client.on_message=on_message
client.on_connect=on_connect
client.connect(broker_address, 1883, 60)
#client.subscribe("button")
client.loop_start()

while 1:
        if button.is_pressed:
               print("button pressed")
               client.publish("button","ON",1)
               sleep(0.1)
        sleep(0.1)
        print("*")
```

Comment: What output are you getting from the script? Are you seeing the `*` being printed 10 times a second?

Comment: Also add a `on_connect` callback and move the `client.subscribe()` call to that callback

Comment: The stars are printing yes.  I will try the on_connect callback and report back.

Comment: def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
        sleep(1)

Comment: Can't get the formatting right, @hardillb i added the callback and it's printing that "Connected with result code" and value zero, but no MQTT packets received/printed.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66689935/edit) the question, do NOT try and add code via comments (but DO NOT call `sleep()` in any of the callbacks)